# How to use special document fields in scripts in elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to write query with custom script in elasticsearch:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html#query-dsl-script-filter
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting.html.

This is useful when you need to compare two document fields.

Everything worked fine, until I decide to use special document field (ex: _id, _uid, etc). The query always returns empty results and there is no errors if I use it like this: `doc['_id'].value`.

So how to use, for example, "_id" field of a document in a custom script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `_id` is indexed in the `uid` field, using this format: `type#id`.

So, your script should look like this (for a type called `my_type` and an ID of `1`):

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script" : {
            "script" : "doc['_uid'].value == 'my_type#1'"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A more elaborate solution, to take out the `id` ES-way is like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.Uid.splitUidIntoTypeAndId(new org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef(doc['_uid'].value))[1].utf8ToString() == '1'"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where `org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.Uid.splitUidIntoTypeAndId(new org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef(doc['_uid'].value))[1]` is the `id` and `org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.Uid.splitUidIntoTypeAndId(new org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef(doc['_uid'].value))[0]` is the `type`.